# ADB Root Grant Root Permission to App or Package

Tags: android, adb, root, bootloader, fastboot

I am having a little trouble with my Development Board it is [Orange Pi 4B](http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%204B/), running [Android 8.1](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/)

Currently I have access to ADB root and also can modify the system folder or even place files inside the system folder but I want to grant Root Permission to my Application which the OS is not allowing. It also has SU placed in xbin folder but when I install SuperSu it says root undetected.

The commands that I try to gain root access to system were

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

These all commands execute with success and I have access to modify the system folder but after trying everything I am still not able to grant SU access to my Application.

Even I tried to flash TWRP but the board is not entering Bootloader with the following command.

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

The main reason I want to grant root permission is to have my app update our company apps in background, I even tried providing the permission to install packages by keeping our apk files into /system/app folder along with the following permission

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```